# Informix 3.30 for DOS

Tags: dos, informix

Do you know where can I download Informix 3.30 for DOS?

I have a system developed in Informix 3.30 for an old machine and want to migrate it now to a PC.

Thanks, Gerardo.

Comment: From wikipedia, "The final release of this product was version 3.30 in early 1986." Wow. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it will be random luck if you find anyone with a copy of Informix 3.30 for DOS that is still readable.  As Steve Prentice comments (quoting Wikipedia), the last release of Informix 3.30 was in 1986, just before I started working with Informix products.  Twenty-five years is a long time in this business.  It is remarkable that you still have the old machine running.

You won't be able to find a legitimate download; the product was released before download sites were common, and went out of service before they were common.

Can you copy the software off the old machine onto your new one?  You're relying on Microsoft to have done an outrageously good job at maintaining backwards compatibility for a quarter century, but it might work.  I am fairly sure the software predates the registry, so you probably can simply copy it all from one machine to another.

I do have the source code compiled and running on a Mac, and would anticipate minimal problems porting it to any other Unix-like system.  Unfortunately, DOS isn't as Unix-like as all that; the terminal handling would be problematic.  What system are you planning to run it on?  Windows 7 directly, or in some sort of compatibility box?  Would Cygwin be an option?  Does your application using custom C code?  Do you still have the source code for the whole application?

What are your plans for migrating to newer technology?

You'd probably best contact me by email - see my profile.

Answer (score 0):

I have an Informix-SQL 2.10 (year 1986) application running with no problems on DOS 6.22, in Microsoft Virtual PC 2007, on Windows XP, Vista and 7. If you cannot find 3.3, the next easiest solution would be to convert your database.dbd data to ISQL's database.dbs and do some minimal re-write of your perform and ace reports.